# Is there a way to install the "make" command on an offline red hat machine?

Tags: linux, redhat

I'm trying to install a driver for my wireless adapter. I don't have any means of connecting to the internet on that machine before I can get the adapter working.

So far I've downloaded the driver folder and transferred it to the offline machine using a USB stick, but it seems like there's no way of compiling the driver without the "make" command. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Well, yes and no... `make` simply interprets the configuration and compile and linker commands from a `Makefile` (basically a compiler/linker script for lack of better words). If you have no way to install GNU make, then you can simply read the `Makefile` and manually compile/link the code. (that may be tedious as `make` was built to make compiling large projects simpler) The GNU `make` executable doesn't have many (if any) dependencies itself. If you have another RedHat box, you can probably copy `/usr/bin/make` from it to your box on a USB drive. (you may grab `/usr/include/gnumake.h` also)

Comment: You need the whole toolchain for compiling drivers, not just make. Maybe find Ethernet USB adapter?

Comment: You can burn the installation iso to your usb device and add your dvd (usb device) as repository in order to install all necessary packages to perform your compilation.